# PyCharm does not recognize functions

Tags: pycharm

I downloaded pycharm a week ago. I define a simple function:

```
 def pyth_test (x1, x2):
    print (x1 + x2)
pyth_test(1, 2)
```

and when I run, I get NameError: name 'pyth_test' is not defined

What is wrong with Pycharm?

Comment: Does this run fine when run from outside of PyCharm, using Python on the command line?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing; pycharm is fine.

1. I just created a new project (without any specific setup)
2. I created a test.py file; pasted your code, hit run; and the console shows the expected

   /usr/bin/python3.5 /data/tmp/test.py
   3

( /data/tmp being a local directory on my machine )

This is with the latest pycharm community, just installed this morning.

So, the "first" answer is: pycharm works just fine. I would recommend:

1. make sure that pycharm found your python installation on your machine
2. create a new project and try fresh

If that still doesn't work; ask for help within the pycharm community forums.

EDIT: actually I just updated my pycharm this morning, I am not sure what exactly I did to install it. But I think, I just started it the first time, and it came back telling my "I found python 2.7 and python 3.5 on your system; should I use them".

What you might want to check: turn to File --- Settings

Click on the section names "Project: yourproject"

and check what "Python" interpreter has to say. On  my system, I got two entries in that pulldown menu; one for 2.7; one for 3.5.

Comment: I tried the 2nd suggestion and still no result. How can I check if Pycharm found my python installation on my machine? Could it be that I miss a libray or something?

Comment: Updated my answer for you. But please understand that I cant be doing much more for you; A) because there isnt so much that I actually could do; and B) honestly, i guess chances are small to receive any upvotes for my work here; and even if you find it worth accepting a not-helpful answer ... makes it even less interesting to spend even more time on this question. For the record: accepting my answer will at least push your rep by +2 ;-)

Comment: @Fotis To find which Python is being used, go to Settings (Preferences on Mac) and then Project->Project Interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

There is a space before your function declaration. Note that Python works on indented tabs/spaces.

Comment: That is correct; but when you put that space there, pycharm immediately marks the corresponding file with red underlining; and when you try to run it, you get a clear message about broken indenting. So, I guess this is not it. But you are correct to point that out.

Comment: yeah that space probably got in when the OP was trying to format it as 'code' on SO (by putting 4 spaces)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure  'pyth_test' is defined,
  I wrote it like this:

```
def pyth_test (x1, x2):
    print (x1 + x2)
```

then hit enter and write:

```
 pyth_test(1, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all there is a space in front of 'def'.

fix that and if it still doesn't work, copy/paste the code into the console.

that seemed to work for me :))